# Skype chats and missed calls keep reappearing

Tags: skype, history

I have Skype 4.2.0.11 on Ubuntu 12.04

I have a recurring problem that a set of skype chats and missed calls keep reappearing as notifications when I startup skype, even though I delete them every time. There is no specific pattern to it that I can see, no specific user or time of day.

Short of clearing all my account history, is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the cache files for the program?

Comment: I would try launching `Skype` from the command line (check if there is a `-v` option to have verbose output) and as you run the program and dismiss these, see if any errors are generated.  It could be as simple as a permission somewhere that is causing it to not save that stuff.

Comment: @nerdwaller Good idea, I get gtk warnings on startup, but no warnings when deleting entries

Comment: @Ramhound where do I find the cache. I specifically don't want to delete the history.

Comment: Backup the history as a precaution then...

Comment: It also happen to me. And often messages are "popped" as if they were sent at that moment but they are very old! (sometimes even more than 1 year!). I also use Ubuntu, perhaps the linux client has some issues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click the notification events in Skype and select "Delete Event"

Answer (score 7):

I've only seen persistent missed calls so far. These seem to occur when connection drops during a call and an immediate subsequent call from the other side is not answered.

This worked for me:

```
update Messages set consumption_status = 0 where type = 30 and consumption_status != 0;
```

(Probably you can drop the whole where clause without messing up anything, but I haven't tried.)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and ended up fixing it as follows:

1. backup ~/.Skype/your_skype_login/main.db
2. open it with some sqlite viewer (I used [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/), a nice QT-based GUI)
3. use [some website](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to convert the date of the annoying unkillable notifications to the Unix timestamp format (don't forget to take the time zone stuff)
4. in the table "Messages", delete rows which have timestamps close to the ones obtained in step 3 and corresponding contents of the "author" field (i.e. don't delete messages from other contacts). Interestingly, this also gets rid of the "Missed call" notifications, even though clearing the "Calls" table doesn't have any effect.
5. Save the changes back to main.db and start Skype again

To narrow down the messages in question, check the *message type* is the one of the notification you want to get rid of:

- 61: Chat message
- 30: Call start
- 39: Call end
- 68: File sent

I still don't know where does this bug stem from

Comment: It seems to work, but I must admit there were that many that I have up on it and just deleted everything.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Pierce is correct and much easier than the accepted answer, but it could do with a slightly better explanation.

I found the clue on the Skype forum: 
http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/cancelled-missed-call-notifications-reappear-on-startup/td-p/2040751

> I had the same problem. Instead of clicking on "mark all viewed,"
>   right click on each notification and then click on "delete entry" in
>   the menu that appears.

So don't use the "mark all viewed", nor the X behind the entries but right click the entry and select "Delete event".

Answer (score 2):

The answers by Loek and Pierce are right. Just to make things a bit easier:

You can click the first entry and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click the last entry, then right click and click "Delete Events" to delete a whole list.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a conversation is not currently supported on Skype for Windows desktop, or Skype for Windows 10.(Source: [Support.Skype.com](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34636/how-do-i-delete-instant-messages-in-skype#))

Comment: Remember this question was for Skype on Linux 4.3 in 2013!

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that....